# What limits the maximum number of connections for a Terminal Server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, terminal-server

We have a several Windows Server 2008 application servers in our organization. Some of them have Terminal Server role enabled. What is the mechanisim that limit the number of user connections for Terminal Server computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the CAL that you have ... More CAL you buy, more connections you have :D

Comment: Yes, but were are those licences, is there some licence server or what?

Comment: Yes you have to setup a terminal license server and add the CAL that you have previously purchased. follow this guide : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325869

Comment: You can setup that on the same TS. The only limit for the number of session will be server resource. The more you have to more users you will have on the TS.

Answer (score 2):

it depends on how many licences you have for the Terminal server. If you haven’t applied any extra licences you are allowed 3 RDP connections (2 Remote 1 Console)

Comment: Yes, but were are those licences, is there some licence server or what?